# JSF Lifecycle - 5th phase is skipped

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I use JSF 2.1 and RichFaces 4.3.7. I have implemented PhaseListener and I have seen that when I click button, `Invoke application Phase` is skipped.

Here is button code:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="${msg['page.util.save']}"
                   action="#{AdminFlyPanelsBean.saveEditedFlyPanel}"
                   render="flyPanelsForm"
                   status="waitStatus" type="submit"
                   oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) #{rich:component('flypanelEditModalPanel')}.hide();">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Anyone knows what is the reason of this?

Comment: What about other phases?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any conversion or validation issue when submitting the form?